# Spring SAXParseException

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to develop an application with spring boot and i have the following html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Hello AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="Hello">
<p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
<p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error and i dont know why, this is the same code as in the example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "ng-app" associated with an element type "html" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Comment: I don't think Spring Boot is doing something special here. Check thymeleaf settings: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#what-kind-of-templates-can-thymeleaf-process. You may also find this discussion useful: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1270

Answer (score 0):

this line seems problematic to me

```
<html ng-app>
```

try this line

```
<html ng-app="">
```

because if you do not want to name your angularJS application then declare as empty. Plus i would suggest use `ng-app=""` in `body`tag instead of `html` tag

Comment: the solution was to add spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5 just as Maks suggested, and yes this also proves to be a solution but it gets annoying to do that all the time

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.

Set the application.properties "spring,thymeleaf.mode" to "LEGACYHTML5".

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

And in the pom.xml, add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
  <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.22</version>
</dependency>
```